# knockout getting the value of changed textox and save it in the database

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js

I have to two textboxes. One is `employeename` and other is worked hours. `employeename` is already prefilled. I have to save work hours for each employee, I have to get the work hours in javascript and save them. I am using knockout. There will be a save button for each row.

How to get the changed worked hours from the texbox after they hit save?

UI(UserInterface)

---

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: arraytoadd">
<tr>
    <td data-bind="text: employeename"></td>
    <td><input id="indynamicntendtime" data-bind="text: workedhours"/></td>  
    <td> <input type="button" id="btnsave" value="save"/> </td>                      
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Javascript

---

```
    Templatefunction = function() 
    {
       var self = this;    
       self.employeename = ko.observavle("");    
       self.workedhours = ko.observale("");
    }    

    RealFunciton = function()
    {
       ver self = this;
       self.arrarytoadd = ko.obeservablearray();
       self.addevent = function ()
       {
         self.arraytoadd.push( new Templatefunction);
       }
    }
```

Getting the values from Ajax and assigning

```
 for(var i=0;i<response.d.length;i++)
 {
     var x = new TemplateFunction();
     x.employeename(response.d[i].EmployeeName);
     x.workedhours(response.d[i].ActualContractorEndTime);
     jobactivityVM.arraytoadd.push(x);
 }


//TO DO  SAVE FUNCIONALITY. On every row save button click i have to get the corresponding workhours

  $(document).on("click", "[id*=btnsave]", function (e) {
      var x = new TemplateFunction();
      var contractorstarttime = Templatefunction["workedhours"]; //HOW TO GET THE CHANGED WORKED    HOURS .
      //start initialising the parameters needed for the ajax call
      var params = {};        
      params.workedhours=workedhours;

  });
```

Comment: Jamiec sorry for the formatting error.I didnt check properly .Please check the quesion now.

Comment: Fixed your formatting, more chance of you getting an answer when its readable.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change some things:

in your viewmodel (e.g. RealFunciton), which is bound to the view add a click-handler

```
 RealFunciton = function()
    {
       ver self = this;
       self.arrarytoadd = ko.obeservablearray();
       self.addevent = function ()
       {
         self.arraytoadd.push( new Templatefunction);
       }

       self.save = function () {
         // here you have access to your viewmodels
         // e.g.
         ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.arraytoadd(), function (item) {
            //do something
         });
         // or with mapping-plugin
         var dataToSave = ko.mapping.toJS(self.arraytoadd);

         // save
       } 
    }
```

in your html-view you have to attach your event-handler:

```
<td> <input type="button" data-bind="click: $parent.save"/> </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user fills in the workedhours input, Knockout will automatically update self.workedhours because of the data-bind on the input.

```
Templatefunction = function()
{
   var self = this;
   self.employeename = ko.observable("");
   self.workedhours = ko.observable("");    //  <----- Knockout will update self.workedhours automatically 
}
```

So in your btnSave click handler just grab self.workedhours:

```
params.workedhours = self.workedhours;
```